# How to clear all arrays in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have soo many arrays in a loop and it takes so much work to write

```
$xarray = array(); 
$yarray = array();
$zarray = array(); 
$tarray = array();
....
```

how can i clear all of them at the end of loop?

If i dont clear arrays at the end of the loop, it just overwrites arrays and sends a ton of wrong value to database. I cant clear every single array because there are too many of them.

edit = i found arrays that i forgot to clear and i fixed it. still a bunch of lines but problem solved.

Comment: I would imagine it takes even more work to create and populate them, doesn't it? What is your use case?

Comment: Use associative arrays.

Comment: @Kingsley if i dont clear them they overwrite. for example array has 9 values if i dont  clear. array gets 18 values. im inserting to database every loop and it sends wrong values. i cleared nearly 40 arrays but still somewhere there is arrays left uncleared and sending wrong values. i cant find them. it takes so much.

Comment: @Marvin im getting datas from html pages and im trying to insert 10 html pages' datas at mysql database at the same time. so i use while loop, and there is toooooo much arrays :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a master array at the start of the loop.

```
$master = array();
```

Then in for your other arrays

```
$master['xarray'] = array();
$master['yarray'] = array();
$master['zarray'] = array();
```

When you are ready to clear you can use

```
unset($master);
```

This will clear the master array and all associated arrays

Comment: $xarray = array(); 
$yarray = array();
$zarray = array(); 
$tarray = array();

is same thing. thank you for your effort though. i found  arrays i forgot to clear and cleared and fixed it. it was a long work

Comment: What is `$foo`? Should that be `unset($master)`?

Comment: it was a typo, meant `$master`. Corrected